# How to solve for $A$ where $A^{-1} = \frac{n}{\text{tr}(A B^{-1})} B^{-1}$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I've worked through a problem and arrived at the equality

$$A^{-1} = \frac{n}{\text{tr}(A B^{-1})}  B^{-1}$$

where both $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices

Looking at it, it seems obvious to say that this equality holds if $A=B$. But how do I say this formally? Is this the only solution?

Comment: I can only see that $AB^{-1}$ must have a constant on the diagonal ($(AB^{-1})_{ii} = \frac{{\rm tr}(AB^{-1})}n$)

Comment: By dimensional analysis, $A=a\cdot 1_n, B=b\cdot 1_n$ work no matter how $a$ and $b$ are related. What you can do, given that both $A$ and $B$ are in fact invertible matrices, set $A=CB$ and multiply the equation by $B$ from the left.

Comment: That's consistent with letting A=B I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the equation on the left by $\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}\tr(AB^{-1})A$ to get $\tr(AB^{-1})I=nAB^{-1}$, so $AB^{-1}$ must be a scalar multiple of the identity, in other words $A$ must a scalar multiple of $B$. Under the condition that the inverses exist (so the scalar had better not be $0$) this necessary condition is also sufficient.

Comment: So the solution set is all $A$ such that $A B^{-1} = q I_K$ where $q = \frac{\text{tr}(A B^{-1})}{n}$. As a result no unique solution exists.

Comment: Actually, just having played around with it, I see that it's the set $A \in \{ q B | q \in R \}$. Thanks

Comment: No, the solution is $A\in\{\, qB\mid q\in\Bbb R, q\neq0\,\}$ (provided that $B$ is invertible to begin with, as is implied b the notation $B^{-1}$).